# polymer test -l chrome: Could not request headers from https://download.microsoft.com

Tags: selenium, polymer, polymer-cli

I am following simple steps to run polymer test but I am facing issues (https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/tools/tests). 
There are few questions in stackoverflow not answered about similar issue.

[Polymer Tests fail waiting for the driver server to start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50031762/polymer-tests-fail-waiting-for-the-driver-server-to-start)

[Polymer2.0 - polymer testing is failing with error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45171684/polymer2-0-polymer-testing-is-failing-with-error)

[Polymer Web Component Tester Unable to connect to selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49020124/polymer-web-component-tester-unable-to-connect-to-selenium)

In case it is relevant I am using Windows 7 and polymer 2.

When I run:

1 - polymer test -l chrome

Result in an error while tring to reach microsoft. Well, very strange since I specify only chrome

```
Error: Could not request headers from https://download.microsoft.com/download/D/
4/1/D417998A-58EE-4EFE-A7CC-39EF9E020768/MicrosoftWebDriver.exe: Error: getaddri
nfo ENOTFOUND download.microsoft.com download.microsoft.com:443
```

2 - polymer test --skip-selenium-install

```
\u00276.1\u0027, java.version: \u00271.8.0_172\u0027\nDriver info: driver.versi
on: unknown","error":"session not created"},"status":33}
   at C:\Users\D-CA69TO\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\polymer-cli\node_modul
es\web-component-tester\runner\steps.js:170:27
   at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
   at fulfilled (C:\Users\D-CA69TO\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\polymer-cli
\node_modules\web-component-tester\runner\steps.js:4:58)
   at <anonymous>
   at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```